# Is it recommended changing the file /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled for MariaDB node?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, linux, galera, redhat

Is it recommended changing the file /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled from 'always' to 'never' for a MariaDB Galera node?

Comment: Note the galera addition to MariaDB isn't a huge memory hog, so if you've got a MariaDB benchmarked system, you should keep whatever setting suites it best. There's decent explicit [large_pages](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#large_pages) support in MariaDB, especially from 10.5+.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, but difficult to say. From what little I know this has a small detrimental effect on performance for typical OLTP workloads but the word “typical” is doing a lot of work there, it could have a performance benefit for your workloads.

Unless you have reason to believe it may be having a significant detrimental effect then I would leave it as-is on the assumption that it has been enabled for a reason. If you do make changes like this then you should benchmark before and after to ensure the difference is as desired (much better still: do this in a test environment that mimics production before considering it in production at all).